# Will accelerating a massive particle generates a blackhole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I have a naive question about blackhole. If I accelerate a massive particle very close to the speed of light, the particle will have large energy-momentum tensor. Will it become a blackhole?